# Is there a good way to change hash salt for password hash?

Tags: encryption, password-encryption

I have a database that stores hashed passwords using a "private salt". However I am afraid that at some point the attacker will somehow know my private salt (for example a developer that leaves the company) and then will be able to do something malicious.

The current logic works like follows

```
function newUser(email, password) {
    // hash is a non-reversible function
    hashedPassword = hash(password, privateSalt);
    databaseStore(email, hashedPassword);
}

function login(email, password) {
    hashedPassword = databaseFetch(email);
    if (password == hashedPassword) {
        loginSuccess();
    }
}
```

Now if I change the privateSalt, all the previously created users will fail with login. Is there a good or standard way to handle this type of situation, so that privateSalt can be changed and previous users can still login?

Comment: You should never store encrypted passwords for verification. Instead you hash them (and use a salt as well). Storing an encrypted passwords allows you to retrieve the original plaintext password which is a terrible security risk! The *only* time when you should consider storing encrypted passwords is if you *must* provide the plaintext to some other service (for example when you're coding a password manager or the like ...).

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant salt for the private key but misused the terminology, I will update my question.

Comment: The salt is randomly generated for each password usually and stored together with the result of the hash. Generally speaking, you should simply use tried-and-tested existing systems instead of building something like this from scratch.

Comment: Also: if you're not actually "encrypting" but "hashing", then please don't call the method `encrypt` and don't call the variable `encryptedPassword`. That's extremely misleading (and makes me suspect that you're also not following other security best practices).

Comment: If you're *actually* hashing with a fixed salt, then the *worst* they can do is to generate a pre-computed dictionary of hashes to check against all of your passwords if they get access to your database. *Usually* you randomly generate the salt for each password to avoid that attack. And if you do that, then the salt is not anything particularly senstive anymore (the salt alone doesn't really help an attacker).

Comment: Thank you for the response. That looks a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution what you are looking for is a password hash, also known as a PBKDF, a password based key derivation function. For this function there are a few algorithms available: PBKDF2, scrypt and Argon2. PBKDF2 is a NIST improved version, scrypt requires attackers to use a lot of memory, and Argon2 is a more modern version of a password hash.

The current scheme has the following issues:

- salts should be random, what you have is essentially a so-called pepper, this means that identical passwords can be found immediately, and if the pepper leaks, then you can perform an attack using a dictionary attack using **rainbow tables**;
- passwords are generally easy to guess, so you need some kind of work factor for each password, which is currently not included.

Now you already have a hash function, probably without a *work factor* or number of iterations in your DB, so you cannot just perform such a function on your existing database.

I see two (non exclusive) options:

1. Indicate to your users that they should update their password: verify their old password and use a known-good & correctly parameterized password hash on the new password. Create a transaction to switch one scheme to the new one. I'd use a different column for the new password, and make sure that *you can update to a new algorithm or work factor* in the future. You want to be able to reliably detect any update/upgrade.
2. You update the hashed password right now by applying a known-good & correctly parameterized password hash *on the already hashed password**, `hashedPassword`. That way your current users get better protection right away.

The disadvantage of (2) is that the **old** DB may be found, in which case your users are screwed, so I'd only combine this strategy with (1).

---

Note that password storage part should only be **part of** the solution. You want to indicate the strength of the chosen password to users. Preferably you want to keep [the option of *longer passphrases* open](https://xkcd.com/936/) (horse staple, XKCD), but still allow shorter more complex ones (as generated by password generators).